# Сумма всех столбцов в динамическом массиве

Tags: c, массивы, указатели, динамические-массивы, локальные-переменные

Хочу посчитать сумму всех столбцов в динамическом массиве, но вместо верного значения  выводятся слишком большие числа

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
int main(){
    int** arr = NULL;
    int n;
    int sum[n];

    printf("input n: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
    arr = (int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * n);
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
        arr[i] = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
}

    srand(time(NULL));
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
        for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
            arr[i][j] = rand() % 51;
           printf("%d\t", arr[i][j]);
}
        printf("\n");
}
for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
      sum[j] += arr[i][j];

for(int j= 0; j < n; j++)
  printf("summa %d stolbtsa =%d", j+1, sum[j]);
    free(arr);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Забыли инициализировать локальный массив

```
int sum[n];
```

В результате суммируете значения с мусором.

```
int sum[n] = {0};
```

должно вас спасти...

Но есть еще одно но - у вас `n` в момент объявления массива тоже содержит мусор :)

Так что я бы, пожалуй, [делал так](https://ideone.com/JU2EMA):

```
int n;

printf("input n: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
int * sum = calloc(n,sizeof(int));
```